# Fastest way to rank trips between two coordinates based on intervening opportunities?

Tags: r, gis, latitude-longitude

I have dataframe with over 5000 places with lat/lon coordinates and I have another dataframe with over 23000 trips with original lat/lon coordinates and destination lat/lon coordinates.

All places and trips are in area of Prague, CZE.

I want to calculate rank of every trip based on intervening opportunities - on sum of all other places closer to the origin. Direction of opportunities doesn't matter.

I tried nested loop to create list of all distances between places, but its slow as hell. (got to 80th place in 10 hours)

```r
for (row in 73:nrow(dataset_2015_POI_prg)) {
    print(row)
    id <- toString(dataset_2015_POI_prg[row, "venue_id"])
    lat <- dataset_2015_POI_prg[row, "venue_lat"]
    lon <- dataset_2015_POI_prg[row, "venue_lon"]

    for (innerrow in 1:nrow(dataset_2015_POI_prg)) {
        innerid <- toString(dataset_2015_POI_prg[innerrow, "venue_id"])
        if (id != innerid && length(which(dataset_2015_POI_mix$from_venue_id == innerid & dataset_2015_POI_mix$to_venue_id == id)) == 0) {
            print(innerrow)
            innerlat <- dataset_2015_POI_prg[innerrow, "venue_lat"]
            innerlon <- dataset_2015_POI_prg[innerrow, "venue_lon"]   
            dist <- distm(c(lon, lat), c(innerlon, innerlat), fun = distHaversine)
            dataset_2015_POI_mix[nrow(dataset_2015_POI_mix) + 1,] = list(id, lat, lon, innerid, innerlat, innerlon, as.numeric(dist))
        }
    }
}
```

Trips dataframe

```
user_id from_lat    from_lon    to_lat      to_lon      distance
159493  50.08017    14.50109    50.09171    14.54276    3241.884096
159493  50.09171    14.54276    50.09076    14.54271    106.390784
159493  50.09076    14.54271    50.11302    14.61078    5456.33700
...
```

Places dataframe

```
venue_id    venue_lat   venue_lon
4adcda9     50.08096    14.42810
...
```

Whats the proper and fastest way to do it? Expected result is new dataframe of trips with new column rank, which is total of all closer places to original place than destionation.

Thanks a lot, I am new to R :)

EDIT:
source files are too big for pastebin or so, so here they are:
trips: http://data.krysp.in/trips.txt
places http://data.krysp.in/pois.txt

EDIT2:
`dput()` of smaller data examples
places:

```
structure(list(venue_lat = c(50.09171, 50.090755, 50.113024, 
50.113251, 50.103708, 50.080167, 50.108774, 50.113106, 50.081854, 
50.104832, 50.090597, 50.113026, 50.068476, 50.113124, 50.10815, 
50.060503), venue_lon = c(14.542765, 14.542707, 14.610781, 14.611714, 
14.490623, 14.501095, 14.577527, 14.611648, 14.500505, 14.476009, 
14.541811, 14.611271, 14.404627, 14.611779, 14.583479, 14.506008
)), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

trips

```
structure(list(user_id = c(159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 
159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 
159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 
159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 159493, 
159493), from_lat = c(50.080167, 50.09171, 50.090755, 50.113024, 
50.113251, 50.113024, 50.103708, 50.080167, 50.108774, 50.113024, 
50.113106, 50.09171, 50.080167, 50.081854, 50.113106, 50.113024, 
50.104832, 50.09171, 50.090597, 50.113024, 50.09171, 50.113026, 
50.113024, 50.068476, 50.113124, 50.113024, 50.09171, 50.113024, 
50.10815, 50.09171), from_lon = c(14.501095, 14.542765, 14.542707, 
14.610781, 14.611714, 14.610781, 14.490623, 14.501095, 14.577527, 
14.610781, 14.611648, 14.542765, 14.501095, 14.500505, 14.611648, 
14.610781, 14.476009, 14.542765, 14.541811, 14.610781, 14.542765, 
14.611271, 14.610781, 14.404627, 14.611779, 14.610781, 14.542765, 
14.610781, 14.583479, 14.542765), from_timestamp = c(10284, 58919, 
58960, 82576, 197020, 1520404, 1539221, 1581079, 1585186, 1586688, 
1586730, 1615656, 1637753, 1640134, 1643362, 1643399, 1659750, 
1756952, 1765592, 1870541, 2000993, 2008701, 2008728, 2541997, 
2653448, 2659355, 2682234, 2727528, 2822921, 2852025), to_lat = c(50.09171, 
50.090755, 50.113024, 50.113251, 50.113024, 50.103708, 50.080167, 
50.108774, 50.113024, 50.113106, 50.09171, 50.080167, 50.081854, 
50.113106, 50.113024, 50.104832, 50.09171, 50.090597, 50.113024, 
50.09171, 50.113026, 50.113024, 50.068476, 50.113124, 50.113024, 
50.09171, 50.113024, 50.10815, 50.09171, 50.060503), to_lon = c(14.542765, 
14.542707, 14.610781, 14.611714, 14.610781, 14.490623, 14.501095, 
14.577527, 14.610781, 14.611648, 14.542765, 14.501095, 14.500505, 
14.611648, 14.610781, 14.476009, 14.542765, 14.541811, 14.610781, 
14.542765, 14.611271, 14.610781, 14.404627, 14.611779, 14.610781, 
14.542765, 14.610781, 14.583479, 14.542765, 14.506008), to_timestamp = c(58919, 
58960, 82576, 197020, 1520404, 1539221, 1581079, 1585186, 1586688, 
1586730, 1615656, 1637753, 1640134, 1643362, 1643399, 1659750, 
1756952, 1765592, 1870541, 2000993, 2008701, 2008728, 2541997, 
2653448, 2659355, 2682234, 2727528, 2822921, 2852025, 3185844
), distance = c(3241.88409599252, 106.39078390924, 5456.33700758756, 
71.2359425785903, 71.2359425785903, 8640.94151730882, 2725.20357275113, 
6319.36823149692, 2420.67310365364, 62.5615027825454, 5464.76021027322, 
3241.88409599252, 192.467213137768, 8665.6776299234, 62.5615027825454, 
9664.83271725758, 4985.72628636199, 141.396853243087, 5521.3444368517, 
5405.101536154, 5436.65634829112, 34.9800594737613, 15536.1468890647, 
15607.2384436169, 72.1080346201786, 5405.101536154, 5405.101536154, 
2023.20076623555, 3435.28409601096, 4354.77279195115)), row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you provide a little more example data? Preferably via `dput()`.

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen I added links to whole dataset, is it ok? Thanks

Comment: I tried to copy it to RStudio and it immeditaly died xD Do you think the first 20 or 30 rows will suffice to comprehend your case? Then you could do: `dput(head(data, n = 30))`

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen I added smaller dumps, check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure if I got what you mean with "ranking the destinantions based on intervening opportunities". This means of course that the same destination can have different ranks based on the different origins of the users. Also I'm not sure if "intervening" should imply the direction between origin and destination.

Anyway this is what I've got:

**Proposal 1** (accounting for direction)

Prepare `trips` df

```
library(sf)

buffers <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(trips)) {
buffers[[i]] <- st_buffer(st_linestring(matrix(as.numeric(trips[i, c(3,2,6,5)]), ncol = 2, byrow = T)), dist = 0.01)
}

buffer_sfc <- st_sfc(buffers, crs = 4326)

sf_trips <- st_sf(trips, geometry = buffer_sfc)
```

Prepare `dest` df

```
sf_dest <- st_as_sf(x = dest, coords = c("venue_lon", "venue_lat"), crs = 4326)
```

Create ranks

```
res <- st_contains(sf_trips, sf_dest)

trips$rank <- sapply(res, length)
```

And this is what it does: Connect origin and destination with a straight line and create a polygon around it. Then all the other destination-points which lie in that polygon are "intervening". You can adjust the size of the polygon via the `dist =` argument in `st_buffer` depending on what deviation from the direct connection still qualifies as "intervening".

[image]

I'm pretty confident that this will run faster than your code. If by "intervening" however you mean any place closer to the origin regardless of direction you can do:

**Proposal 2**

```
library(RANN)


intv_ops <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(trips)) {
  intv_ops[[i]] <- nn2(dest, trips[i, 2:3], searchtype = "radius", radius = (trips$distance[i]/1.11) * 0.00001)$nn.idx
}

trips$rank <- sapply(intv_ops, function(x) sum(x != 0))
```

`nn2`is a wrapper for a knn-algorithm wirtten in C++, so it's pretty fast.

Comment: You are right, I wrote it incorrectly. I am trying to rank the trips. Direction of oportunities doesn't matter. I will update my question and try your proposals.

Comment: I am trying Proposal 2, as the direction doesn't matter. Your code works great, however the maximum rank is 10 and I am pretty sure there should be more sometimes. Is there way to fix it? :)  Thank you so much, your solution is really fast :)

Comment: There is the `k = ` argument with wich you can increase or decrease the number of nn you are looking for. Try to increase it.

Comment: Always glad to help!